# Change label CSS when child radio button is selected (without using javascript/jquery)?

Tags: html, css, mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo MVVM and i want to change the CSS of my label when its child radio button is selected. I have my HTML setup like this:

```html
<label class="oneToOne typeBlock" data-bind="css: { selected: SubType == 'onetoone' }">
  <input name="transformType" class="hidden" type="radio" value="onetoone" data-bind="checked: SubType" />
  <span class="typeDescription">One to One</span>
</label>

<label class="expression typeBlock" data-bind="css: { selected: SubType == 'expression' }">
  <input name="transformType" class="hidden" type="radio" value="expression" data-bind="checked: SubType" />
  <span class="typeDescription">Expression</span>
</label>
```

This setup works in that the value of the property `SubType` in my model is set to either `onetoone` or `expression` on clicking the label, but the label does not get the `selected` class when the specified condition is met.. is there a way to do this? or is the `CSS` data-bind only working with strict booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @3rdthemagical's help in introducing me to the `+` css operator, i was able to achieve my goal without using any javascript/jquery. Here's my HTML/CSS:

```css
.radio:checked + .typeBlock {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="test1" name="transformType" class="radio hidden" type="radio" value="onetoone" data-bind="checked: SubType" />
<label for="test1" class="oneToOne typeBlock">
  <span class="typeDescription">One to One</span>
</label>


<input id="test2" name="transformType" class="radio hidden" type="radio" value="expression" data-bind="checked: SubType" />
<label for="test2" class="expression typeBlock">
  <span class="typeDescription">Expression</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code changes styles for the span after checked input.

```
input:checked + span {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
input:checked + span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="oneToOne typeBlock" data-bind="css: { selected: SubType == 'onetoone' }">
  <input name="transformType" class="hidden" type="radio" value="onetoone" data-bind="checked: SubType" />
  <span class="typeDescription">One to One</span>
</label>

<label class="expression typeBlock" data-bind="css: { selected: SubType == 'expression' }">
  <input name="transformType" class="hidden" type="radio" value="expression" data-bind="checked: SubType" />
  <span class="typeDescription">Expression</span>
</label>
```

Comment: This is very close to what i want, but not _exactly_... I want that when the radio button is checked, the `label` tag (not the sibling span) that corresponds to it gets the modified CSS, can this be done while my input is inside my label? or do i have to separate them

Comment: @philr Css doesn't have prev element selector. Or `parent` selector. So while `input` is inside a `label` tag, you can't modify `label`. Why do you need to modify exactly 'label'?

Comment: my `label` tags are mimicking buttons, when one of the labels are clicked i want it to appear "pressed in". i know i can do this easily using jQuery i was just wondering if it could be done without it

Answer (score 0):

In kendo MVVM, in the data-bind, you specify a property or function on your view model. You cannot bind to an expression like SubType == 'onetoone'. In css class bindings, the binding should be to a boolean property or a function that returns one.

Take this binding in the html as an example:

```
data-bind="css: { selected: isOneToOne }
```

In your viewmodel, you could have a property such as:

```
isOneToOne: false;
```

This would mean the 'selected' class is not applied. If you then do this within your viewmodel:

```
set("isOneToOne", true);
```

...the class then becomes applied. Alternatively, isOneToOne could be a function on your viewmodel returing a boolean:

```
isOneToOne: function () {
    return get("SubType") === 'onetooone';
}
```